# Unit and Integration testing of custom Kong plugin using busted

Tags: lua, kong, kong-plugin, lua-busted

I have been trying to explore unit and integration testing frameworks for custom kong plugins. I'm very new to Lua and I started exploring busted and I was **not** able to successfully run tests on the plugin.

Here are the steps I followed -

1. I ran a Docker container of kong version 2.5.0
2. Inside the kong docker container I cloned https://github.com/Kong/kong repo
3. when I try to run some tests from the above repository's spec folder i get error as `./kong/tools/utils.lua:37: attempt to index global 'ngx' (a nil value)`

I'm following [this](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/plugin-development/tests/) documentation, to understand writing and running unit and integrtion tests in kong, but I'm having hard time setting up the environment.

Any help in setting up a docker container to run unit and integration tests in kong using busted is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at Pongo? https://github.com/Kong/kong-pongo

Comment: https://medium.com/p/2e4bad9d6178 I have written 3 articles about plugins testing

Comment: Tried Pongo, and I went ahead with it.